# В чем разница между nth-child и nth-of-type?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, nth-of-type

не могу понять в чем разница между nth-child и nth-of-type в css?

Например я использую:

```
.container .elem:nth-child(1) {
  property: value
}
```

Но это не всегда срабатывает для первого или n-ного элемента.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Введение

`p:nth-child(2)` сработает для второго элемента (выборка происходит среди всех элементов, вне зависимости типа; не важно `p`, `li` или `a`), который является `p`, если второй элемент во вложенности не `p` то он не сработает.

`p:nth-of-type(2)` сработает для, именно, второго `p`, если вообще есть такой элемент или количество таких элементов больше или равно 2.

### Пример №1

Если у тебя во вложенном блоке элементы одного типа, то разницы между двумя данными псевдоклассами вы не увидите.

### nth-child

```css
div p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

div p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Первый параграф</p>
  <p>Второй параграф</p>  <!-- Нужен этот элемент -->
</div>
```

### nth-of-type

```css
div p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

div p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Первый параграф</p>
  <p>Второй параграф</p>  <!-- Нужен этот элемент -->
</div>
```

### Пример №2

Если вы добавите, допустим, заголовок в начало, то `p:nth-child(2)` сработает для первого параграфа (второй элемент по порядку, который соответствует типу `p`).

В случае с `p:nth-of-type(2)` выбор будет происходить только среди элементов `p`, а второй по счету `p`, это то что нам нужно.

### nth-child

```css
div p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

div p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Первый заголовок</h1>
  <p>Первый параграф</p>
  <p>Второй параграф</p>  <!-- Нужен этот элемент -->
</div>
```

### nth-of-type

```css
div p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

div p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Первый заголовок</h1>
  <p>Первый параграф</p>
  <p>Второй параграф</p>  <!-- Нужен этот элемент -->
</div>
```

Абсолютно тот же принцип работает для `first-child` и `first-of-type`, если считать, что `first-child` равно `nth-child(1)` и `first-of-type` равно `nth-of-type(1)`.

Думаю довольно понятно объяснение, если есть вопросы могу дополнить ответ.

Comment: зачет! ответил четко и понятно

Comment: спасибо большое!